# Why Http Post is working only for API 10?

Tags: php, android, mysql

this is my code

```
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nama", nama));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pesan", s));

                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.173.1/chatgroup/insert.php");
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();
                    textchat.setText("");
                    getData();

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
                    Log.e("ClientProtocol", "Log_tag");
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    Log.e("IOException", "Log_tag");
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Im build this in API 10[Gingerbread] and working successfully,...

But if im build for API 11> is not working and force close the app.. anyone here can give me suggest,.. or this code only work in api 10?

Note: im using uses-permision Internet in manifest.xml :D thank you for your respond

Comment: Off Topic : dont use HttpPost etc.. at all. this was removed on API 6.0...

Comment: Please post a stacktrace from LogCat if it's crashing, or edit your post to provide a clear description of what isn't working

Comment: `using uses-permision Internet `. That is wrong. You should request for `INTERNET`.

Comment: i did it add an internet permission on manifest.xml...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
 try {
                URL url = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    postDataParams.put("nama", nama);
                    postDataParams.put("pesan", s);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                out.print(postDataParams);
                out.close();

                int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: im tried it and no response on server bro ^^, thanks for answer,.. any some change before thats code?

Comment: r u get response now?

Comment: still no response, i'll try combine it with asyntask fir ^^

Comment: what is responseCode value? like,200,401,400.

Answer (score 0):

That code will work now too. But you have to place that code in an AsyncTask or thread.

Now you have a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` clearly visible in the LogCat.